# What are the fictional dates of Raven's Home?

Tags: ravens-home, thats-so-raven

There is considerable evidence that the fictional dates of the Disney shows *Jessie* and its sequel *Bunk'd* are earlier dates than the dates that the episodes were broadcast, or to put it another way, that the episodes were broadcast at dates after their fictional dates.

Emma Ross was allegedly born on April 19, 1998, according to a wiki - https://disneychannelsjessie.fandom.com/wiki/Emma_Ross. - and in the third season episode of *Bunk'd* "Let's Bounce", June 19, 2018, Emma says she should be in charge of Camp Kikiwaka since she is eighteen years old.  Thus the third season episodes of *Bunk'd* should happen in the summer of 2016 when Emma is 18.  And that is two years before they were broadcast.

It is said in an episode of *Jessie* that Ravi was born on March 24, 2001, and that is certainly canonical.  Ravi's eighteen birthday would be March 24, 2019, so Ravi could be younger than eighteen in every summer up to the summer of 2018.  But since it seems likely that Ravi is more than just one year younger than Emma, 2017 or 2016 seem like plausible dates for the third season of *Bunk'd*, and thus 2017 to 2018 seem like plausible dates for the fourth season of *Bunk'd*, and if the fifth season of *Bunk'd* is ever made and is supposed to happen the year after the fourth season, 2018 or 2019 would seem like a plausible fictional date for it.

So if the creators of any hypothetical fifth season of *Bunk'd* don't want to mention the COVID-19 pandemic of 2020 to 2021, they have a good excuse, the fact that the fictional date of that hypothetical fifth season should be 2018 or 2019.

But there is a cross over episode of *Raven's Home* "Raven about Bunk'd", shown between the third and fourth season of *Raven's Home* on 24 July 2020, in which the character travels to Maine and meets the characters of the fourth season of *Bunk'd*.

So what are the fictional dates, if any, of *Raven's Home* episodes?

In the three-part "Sleevemore" series in the second season of *Raven's Home* from Sept 21 to October 5, 2018, Raven meets Dr. Sleevemore who was in some episodes of "That's So Raven".  If they mention how long it is since they saw each other, that would date *Raven's Home* relative to "That's So Raven".

If Raven and Chelsea mention how long they have been friends in an episode of "That's So Raven", and do so again in an episode of *Raven's Home* the difference would indicate the time span between the two episodes and shows.

So does anyone know any evidence whether the fictional dates of *Raven's Home* agree with the fictional dates of *Bunk'd*, or if the dates of the two series contradict each other, which would not be surprising?

Added 05-01-2021.

There is a fifth season of *Bunk'd*, broadcast beginning on January 15, 2021.  The character of Gwen Flores is not present in the 5th season.  Since Gwen is at Camp Kickiwaka in "Raven about Bunk'd" on July 24, 2020. the fifth season should have a fictional date in the summer after "Raven about Bunk'd".

So the time between the 3rd and 4th seasons of *Raven's Home* should happen at about the time of the 4th season of *Bunk'd*.  So the 5th season of *Bunk'd* should happen at roughly the same time as the 4th season of *Raven's Home*.

In the 4th season of *Raven's Home* episode "Bless This Tess", April 30 2021, there is mention of a lockdown and the need to isolate.  This seems like a reference to the COViD 19 pandemic.  There should have been restrictions in Chicago at various times in 2020 and 2021.

So the fictional dates of the 4th season of *Raven's Home* and the 5th season of *Bunk'd* should happen during 2020 or 2021.  This is inconsistent with the conclusion in the third paragraph of this question that:

> ...and if a fifth season of *Bunk'd* is ever made and is supposed to happen the year after the fourth season, 2018 or 2019 would seem like a plausible fictional date for it.

[Will the fifth season of Bunk'd reference the coronavirus pandemic?](https://moviechat.org/tt4591680/Bunkd/5e9e0bb6ee346205ae92e507/Will-the-fifth-season-of-Bunkd-reference-the-coronavirus-pandemic?reply=608e0751c120277aeee19ba0&animate=false)

[Emma's Age](https://moviechat.org/tt4591680/Bunkd/5e97fa6b2d834940a46df9a9/Emmas-Age?reply=608e072ec120277aeee19b9b&animate=false)

Comment: Are these dates relevant? Isn't this just a case of https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ComicBookTime ?

Comment: @– BCdotWEB  I personally hate comic book time, and was annoyed occassionally watching soap operas to note that they also use what could be called comic book or soap opera time.  In the case of Raven's Home and Bunk'd the fictional dates of Bunk'd episodes seemed to be 2 years before they were broadcast, so a hypothetical  future Bunk'd season could be set before the Covid-19 epidemic even if filmed after it, which has practical implications for the writers of the episodes..

Comment: Why don't you have a bunk'd or jessie tag?